# Power BI Fields Blue vs White Table Symbols

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm looking through a Power BI Desktop file and noticed that some of the tables in the Field pane are light blue and some are white. What do each of these signify?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue ones are [calculated tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables), while the white ones are coming from the data source.

Comment: Yes, the white ones are loaded from the Query Editor and the others are defined via DAX code and are not modifiable in the Query Editor.